# MATE Terminal; has stopped working; returns "Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:"

Tags: linux, bash

I installed the MATE desktop environment into my onprem EC2 instance as per this URL;
`https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/`

And was able to kick-off terminal commands such as;
`mate-terminal --window --zoom=2 --geometry=30x12 --command timer.sh &`

Which opened a terminal window and looped over printing the date and time until killed.

Now, I get
**Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:**

I think this might be due to the following, as it caused problems with TigerVNC ;
`$> chmod 775 /home/ec2-user`

I have tried setting DISPLAY to "localhost:0.0" and ":0.0" but to no avail.

I know its related to gnome but I just can't find enough documentation, so any help is appreciated?

Chris

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: No, it's not related to GNOME. It's related to needing `DISPLAY` to point to a socket that X11Vnc is actually serving on; and/or needing other X11-related configuration such as XAuth. In any event, this is not the place.

Comment: @Barmar - thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/ says "MATE is a fork of the now unmaintained GNOME 2." But putting that aside, yes, this is a permission or socket problem.

Comment: Sure, that's where MATE came from, but that doesn't mean it won't run on its own without other GNOME components -- it absolutely should (as long as the libraries it's linked to are present). Just as one can use gnome-terminal in KDE, one should be able to use MATE terminal without any "desktop environment" at all, as long as you have a working X server.